# Acessar Pseudo Elementos ::after e ::before e Outros

Tags: jquery, css

É possível acessar um elemento `::after` criado no **CSS** com **jQuery** ?

Por exemplo:

```
ul.pager{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    max-width: 960px;
    z-index: 30;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    height: 65px;
    background: url(../img/contador/contador.png) no-repeat right;
    font-size: 0px;
    &:after{
            content: "";
            width: 42px;
            right: -12px;
            height: 41px;
            position: absolute;
            background: url(../img/contador/seta-proxima.png) no-repeat center;
            top: 14px;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
    }
    li{
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        &:first-child{
            >a, span{
                background: url(../img/contador/anterior.png) no-repeat center;
                height: 54px;
                width: 50px;
                right: 130px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 9px;
                transition: all 0.2s ease;
            }
            &:hover{
                > a, span{
                    transform: scale(1.1);
                }
            }
        }
        &:last-child{
            >a, span{
                background: url(../img/contador/proxima.png) no-repeat center;
                height: 59px;
                width: 50px;
                right: 80px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 9px;
                transition: all 0.2s ease;
            }
            &:hover{
                > a, span{
                    transform: scale(1.1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Esses elementos são criados pelo `render()` do **Laravel**. É uma paginação na qual estilizei.

Preciso acessar o elemento `::after` com **jQuery** para aplicar um LINK. Eu não tenho acesso direto aos elementos, pois eles são criados dinamicamente e a única coisa que é definida é uma `class="pager"` para o `ul`.

No `ul` criei um `::after`. Já li sobre colocar uma classe no `ul` e chamar o `::after` nela. Mas nesse caso não posso como expliquei acima.

Tem alguma outra forma ?

Comment: Tenho uma pequena impressão que essa pergunta é duplicada

Comment: Não, não é duplicada. Vi ela no [SOEN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Comment: Algumas referências aqui - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin/21709814#21709814

Comment: Tem mais aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com o jQuery não é possível acessar os pseudo elementos.

O que pode ser feito é utilizar as funções `after` e `before` do jQuery, porém as mesmas criarão os dados no `DOM`, não serão apenas pseudo elementos.

O que pode ser feito:

```
 $('.pager').find('ul').after('Insira o que quiser aqui');
```

Comment: Usar o `.after()` não tem muito a ver com o `::after` do CSS...